# 8086 OS-less programming; segmentation

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16

Well folks, this is a hard-to-place question, as it deals with a lot of hardware specifics, so I had a thought to put it to EE.SE, but the primary focus of this is programming, so I decided to stick it here.

I've recently got a big blast of nostalgia (as well as itch to get back into CPU intrinsics), so I decided to homebrew a 8086 microcomputer board. Granted that I'm familiar with x86 assembly (to a degree, as you'll see) and I already know how to get my code on to the computer board, let's get to the actual problem. For the purposes of being informed, I'm using NASM although I'm not fully up-to-speed on its syntax yet.

Obviously, an 8086 working in The Mode (Real Mode not being called Real Mode yet) has the first 1,024 bytes separated aside at the beginning for 255 2+2 byte interrupt vectors, so the actual instruction listings start at `0x3FF`.

The problem here is because of the quirks of the system's memory segmentation, as well as the fact that I might as well be writing a BIOS, from how the system is concerned. Do the segment registers have to be set, and if so, how do I determine what to put there? Suppose I'm using EEPROM or some form of Flash for my code storage, so I have something of the sort:

```
section .text
org 0x0000
    ; Interrupt vectors reserved
    ivt: times 1024 db 0
main:
    cli      ; Clear out interrupts because no addresses are defined yet
             ; Problems HERE.
             ; Set up interrupt addresses
```

I know that may be horribly-bad and most likely obviously-wrong syntax, but it illustrates the point I'm trying to make. Do I have to set the segmentation registers manually, via something like `mov CS, blahblahblah`, and if so, how do I determine the addresses the different segments/sections in my code body occur at?

The title of this question gives reference to the fact that although I've done a lot of Googling, I couldn't for the life of me find a reference to operating-system-less programming of an 8086. All the sources I could find assumed I was writing for a system already in place where the interrupt vectors and segments and such were already set up and figured out, whereas I'm trying to make a knockoff microcontroller that does everything from the ground up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to me that you're asking where to put the boot code.

When you start up the machine, straight out of reset, `CS` (the code segment) has this value:

- selector: `0ffffh`
- base: `0ffff0h`

and `IP` (the instruction pointer), has the value `00000h`.

Adding `CS.base` and `IP` gives a starting point of `0ffff0h`.

Note that this doesn't leave you much room to work in - only 16 bytes before you run out of memory, but it's enough for you to put a far jump into wherever you want to put your code.

Comment: Correct me if I'm misunderstanding, but if that holds true, that means the top of processor memory is 4GB, which isn't addressable by  the 8086...physically or otherwise.

Comment: @blasthash: you're right.  I was answering based on my knowledge of 80386.  I updated my answer.

Comment: Using a CPU before the 80286 the CPU always is in "real mode" which means that the segment "base" always is 10h*selector. These CPUs did not know about "limits" so a 16-bit access to address seg:0FFFFh is possible; however 8086, 80186 and modern CPUs behave differently in this case so you should not do this. For addresses >= 100000h bit 20 is cut off (so FFFF:FFFF is address 00FFEFh, not 10FFEFh).

Comment: Took me awhile due to the holiday cheer today, but I figure my initial wording wasn't as clear as it should be. Put simply, I'm looking on how to either a) structure my assembly in a manner to allow me to figure out the segments, and b) how to set those segments programmatically without me having to write fixed addresses that will change on revision. Does this illustrate the problem I'm having better?

Comment: Here's a more directed question - since you said that 16 bytes are allotted at the very top of the address space, that is space for 8 opcodes - would it be possible to redirect the the code segment there, prior to the far jump, such that I can place my code directly after the interrupt vector addresses?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  You can put the code segment directly after the IDT, but you still have to perform a far jump to there from 0xffff0 immediately after reset.

Comment: @NathanFellman That's exactly what I was getting at. In NASM, would the instruction `jmp 0x0000:<label>` be legal?

Answer (score 4):

The 8086 uses a very simple form segmentation where every memory reference is based off of one of the four segment registers, `CS`, `DS`, `SS`, or `ES`. That means segmentation is always used on every memory access whether it's explicit in the instruction or not. To resolve a memory reference the CPU multiplies the value in the appropriate segment register by 16 and adds it to 16-bit offset giving a 20-bit physical address. This is what's called real-mode segmentation in modern Intel processors.

The `CS` register determines the base of the code segment. All instruction fetches are done in this segment, at the offset supplied by the `IP` register. As Nathan Fellman's answer indicates `CS:IP` is loaded with `FFFF:0000` during processor initialization, giving a stating physical address of `FFFF0h`, so you'll need to have an EEPROM or something at this address. As your question notes, you'll also probably also want some form memory at the beginning of the physical address space for the interrupt vector table.

Where you locate anything else is up to you. You'll want to load the `DS` register so it points to where want to store most of your data, as most memory operands use this segment by default. You'll probably also want to have a stack so you'll also need load `SS` (and `SP`) with a suitable value. You can load the same value into `SS` as `DS` if you want. The `ES` register doesn't need to be loaded with any particular value, as only a few instructions use it implicitly (`MOVS`, `SCAS`, `CMPS`). You'll probably want to it free to use as an "extra" scratch segment register to access regions of memory other than those referred by `CS`, `DS`, or `SS`.

Note that assumes that you have a real Intel 8086 or 80186 processor. If you actually have a 80286 or later processor that you only want to use in real mode then starting address will be different. If you have some sort of clone 8086 processor you should consult it's datasheet to see if it also does anything different.

Answer (score 1):

> ...I've done a lot of Googling, I couldn't for the life of me find a reference to operating-system-less programming of an 8086...

For OS-less, BIOS-less 8086 programming you may use as valuable source of information some BIOS source codes. Like this one:

> http://bochs.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/lxr/source/bios/rombios.c#L11661
>
> ...
>   // Copyright (C) 2002  MandrakeSoft S.A.
>   ...
>   // ROM BIOS for use with Bochs/Plex86/QEMU emulation environment
>   ...
>
> ```
> .org 0xfff0 ; Power-up Entry Point
>   jmp 0xf000:post
>   ...
> post:
>   xor ax, ax
>    ...
> normal_post:
> ; case 0: normal startup
>
>   cli
>   mov  ax, #0xfffe
>   mov  sp, ax
>   xor  ax, ax
>   mov  ds, ax
>   mov  ss, ax
>   ...
> ```

---

See also:

- [Combined Volume Set of Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html)

  - **9.1.4 First Instruction Executed**

    > The first instruction that is fetched and executed following a hardware reset is located at physical address `FFFFFFF0H`. This address is 16 bytes below the processor’s uppermost physical address. The `EPROM` containing the software initialization code must be located at this address...
  - **9.7 SOFTWARE INITIALIZATION FOR REAL-ADDRESS MODE OPERATION**

    > Following a hardware reset (either through a power-up or the assertion of the `RESET#` pin) the processor is placed in real-address mode and begins executing software initialization code from physical address `FFFFFFF0H`. Software initialization code must first set up the necessary data structures for handling basic system functions, such as a real-mode `IDT` for handling interrupts and exceptions. If the processor is to remain in *real-address mode*...
    >
    > If the processor is going to operate in *protected mode*...